# How to Call Plugin Controller function from own controller in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

How to call plugin controller function from own controller? I have created a plugin but when I am calling the plugin function from my controller I am getting the error

> Class Not Found

I have created a folder in `app/Plugin/Myplugin/Controller/PluginController`
and I want to call `Plugincontroller function from MyController`. MyController is in `App/Controller/MyController`.

This is `MyController` Code.

```
<?php
App::uses('Controller', 'PluginController.Controller');
class MyController extends AppController {
    public function index() {
        $this->autoRender=false;
        $d=new PluginController();
        $d->index();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The simple answer is you shouldn't be sharing methods between controllers like this in CakePHP. If there is shared functionality it should go in a [component](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html):-

> Components are packages of logic that are shared between controllers.